# sql 1 table row with hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 dropdowns that are dependent on eachother and they are populated   with data from 5 tables from a sql database. The last dropdown is populated with data from a column with hyperlinks, like: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com

What should I add to my 5th dropdown to go to that linked site? It interprets the column at this moment as text. The dropdown is a styled version of a simple:

```
<select>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: you'll need some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Give that `select` some id, f.e:

```
<select id="selectbox_with_url">
  <option></option> // here will be your items
</select>
```

And then use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urlmenu = document.getElementById('selectbox_with_url');

    urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      // if you want to open it on new tab (or popup) - depends on browser settings:
      window.open(this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_blank');
      // or if you want to follow that location from option's selected item:
      window.location = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value;
    };
</script>
```

**window.open(URL,name,specs,replace):
where name:**

```
_blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
_parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
_self - URL replaces the current page
_top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
name - The name of the window (Note: the name does not specify the title of the new window)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, beacuse this dropdown is dependent on the previous dropdown. So it wants to go to the id of the category of the table of which it is a subcategory.

Comment: So please add your HTML, we can't know, what's depend on what without showing more of your code.

Comment: The first problem I have that my dropdowns do not show the hyperlink. I stored this is as VARCHAR: <a href='http://nos.nl'>nos</a>. The other rows in this column also do not show up, even if they are plain text.

Comment: `<option value="www.nos.nl">nos.nl</option>`. Please, follow docs - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: do you mean it has to be stored in sql like this?

Comment: In sql store just the link, ie. `nos.nl` or `www.nos.nl`